# Cordova could not load API for android project

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I've been trying to run android project using Visual Studio 2017 and Cordova. When i try to run the app on the android emulator from command prompt it doesnt work and said that it could not load API for the android project from API.js. Is there any thing I can do to fix the problem?

Attached is the screenshot from the command prompt with the error mentioned.

I have tried to use the command `cordova emulate android` but to no avail.

Comment: Is this a new project? Did you run `npm i` prior to this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed easily by removing and adding platform again as mentioned below.

```
cordova platform rm android
```

and then add it again

```
cordova platform add android@latest
```

**Note:** Keep a backup of `platforms/android` as sometime user have manually added changes in platform folder, so that will be lost.
`@latest` was added just to make sure you are using all latest feature, you can avoid that if not needed or want to use a specific version, then use that.

Answer (score 1):

remove platform android,
then add it back again this should solve your problem ,

Answer (score 0):

I would you advise you to avoid Visual Studio for Cordova development. As far as I know they discontinued the support for Cordova and you might be using a very old version.

You can manage your Cordova project with the official command line interface and edit your code with the editor of your chossing like Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code.

Make sure to use the [latest version of the documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html) and prepare your environment for the platforms like [Android](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html)

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the resposne. What is the official command line interface you mentioned? I've tried using the listed instructions in https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/ but when I tried to run "cordova emulate android" or "cordova run android" it stills gives me the same error.

Comment: I added a comment about that to the answer

Comment: Any luck on this error?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I have to thank you for not wasting any more of my time. I had been looking at old tutorials using vs code for cordova development

Answer (score 0):

First remove all node modules:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Then install them again:

```
npm i
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: Not fixed for me.

Comment: Try to remove and add your platform. This is normally easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution,
root cause is package.json
type must be commonjs

remove
"type": "module"
or change to "type": "commonjs" first
and then
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android